# Best solution for client - server architecture

Tags: python, architecture, client-server, desktop

I have an application and there are two logical parts for it.

1. Core algorithm proprietary logic written in Python.
2. Winform application on desktop.

I do not want to have my core algorithm to be exposed on the client-side due to security issue. Since it is written in python want to have it in server and my Winform App (C#.net) can connect to the server through some mean.

Please suggest some architecture diagrams to achieve this so that I can safeguard my core algorithm.

Comment: What constraints do you have, if any, regarding where the algorithm is to be hosted?  E.g. is *aaS ok or do you want to host it on-premise?

Comment: No I can host in any cloud servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution I can think of would be to host the Python algorithm on a *aaS solution, and have that expose your algorithm via an API.

In terms of *aaS providers for Python, there are heaps of options, e.g. [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/#overview) might be an option for you.  An advantage of a platform like Azure / GCP / AWS is that they are pretty mature and will have all the tools you need to expose you algorithm through an API, manage security, etc.

[Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python): Create a function in Azure with Python using Visual Studio Code

**Basic Architecture**

For the overall architecture, in simple terms, all you simply need to point your app at the API which exposes your algorithm.

[image]

- Blue elements: your code / system.
- Green element: the *aaS runtime environment, hosting, networking, storage, etc.

In the diagram above, I have assumed that:

- When you migrate the algorithm onto the *aaS platform, you create an appropriate API for it, so that it can be called by the desktop application in a sensible way.
- You're using something like Azure Functions (as the runtime) which can be used to host the algorithm as an API, exposed to the internet directly.
- Your desktop app has a layer which neatly handles the service access - just like you might do for database access code, so that it's not littered through your app.
- You have a config file (or some other mechanism) that allows operators of the app to point to wherever the algorithm is hosted.

**Production Architecture**

The above (simple) architecture will work, but it's not production grade.

[image]

- Blue elements: your code / system.
- Green elements: the *aaS runtime environment, hosting, networking, storage, etc.
- Red element: DNS / networking, which might sit outside your *aaS provider, or inside it (or both).

Description:

- Similar to the simple architecture except that we add some kind of API gateway to de-couple where requests hit the *aaS platform, and your service implementation.  That way you can swap out service implementations without affecting consumers.  A proper API gateway will also provide a more complete range of management & operational features.
- DNS, e.g. [www.myawesomepythonalgorithm.net](http://www.myawesomepythonalgorithm.net) allows you to control which *aaS provider service traffic gets sent to, assuming you wanted to switch from Azure to GCP (and assuming the services URL structure was the same).
- Security!  Not shown on the diagram, but presumably you'll need to decide how you want to protect the algorithm from unauthorized access.

Comment: Thanks @adrian. That was detail explaination. I will explore more on that.

Comment: The above suggestions were very much useful.